# Solr term frequency results are getting wrong

Tags: solr

I am using solr v6.0.1.I indexed few word and pdf documents to the solr using following query.

```
$this->solr_url . "/update/extract?literal.id=" . $doc_id . "&commit=true";
```

I didn't changed any setting in schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files.When i query the solr using the following [link](http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?debugQuery=on&indent=on&q=java&wt=json).

I am getting in accurate term frequency counts like this:

```
"1466760741Brahmini.doc":"\n1.4220589 = weight(_text_:java in 748) [], result of:\n  1.4220589 = score(doc=748,freq=86.0 = termFreq=86.0\n)
```

Please help me to get the accurate values

Comment: What did you expect the values to be? What is an 'accurate value'?

Comment: Why are these results inaccurate?